Split array of integers into subarrays with the biggest sum of difference between min and max
I'm trying to find the algorithm efficiently solving this problem:

Given an unsorted array of numbers, you need to divide it into several subarrays of length from a to b, so that the sum of differences between the minimum and maximum numbers in each of the subarrays is the greatest. The order of the numbers must be preserved.
Examples:
a = 3, b = 7
input: [5, 8, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1]
answer: [[5, 8, 4], [5, 1, 3], [5, 1, 3, 1]] (diff sum is 12)

a = 3, b = 4
input: [1, 6, 2, 2, 5, 2, 8, 1, 5, 6]
answer: [[1, 6, 2], [2, 5, 2, 8], [1, 5, 6]] (diff sum is 16)

a = 4, b = 5
input: [5, 8, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1, 2]
answer: splitting is impossible


The only solution I've come up with so far is trying all of the possible subarray combinations.
from collections import deque

def partition_array(numbers, min_len, max_len):
  max_diff_subarray = None

  queue = deque()

  for end in range(min_len - 1, max_len):
    if end < len(numbers):
      diff = max(numbers[0:end + 1]) - min(numbers[0:end + 1])
      queue.append(Subarray(previous=None, start=0, end=end, diff_sum=diff))

  while queue:
    subarray = queue.popleft()

    if subarray.end == len(numbers) - 1:
      if max_diff_subarray is None:
        max_diff_subarray = subarray
      elif max_diff_subarray.diff_sum < subarray.diff_sum:
        max_diff_subarray = subarray
      continue

    start = subarray.end + 1

    for end in range(start + min_len - 1, start + max_len):
      if end < len(numbers):
        diff = max(numbers[start:end + 1]) - min(numbers[start:end + 1])
        queue.append(Subarray(previous=subarray, start=start, end=end, diff_sum=subarray.diff_sum + diff))
      else:
        break

  return max_diff_subarray

class Subarray:
  def __init__(self, previous=None, start=0, end=0, diff_sum=0):
    self.previous = previous
    self.start = start
    self.end = end
    self.diff_sum = diff_sum

numbers = [5, 8, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1]
a = 3
b = 7
result = partition_array(numbers, a, b)
print(result.diff_sum)

Are there any more time efficient solutions?

First let's solve a simpler problem. Let's run through an array, and give mins and maxes for all windows of fixed size.
def window_mins_maxes (size, array):
    min_values = deque()
    min_positions = deque()
    max_values = deque()
    max_positions = deque()

    for i, value in enumerate(array):
        if size <= i:
            yield (i, min_values[0], max_values[0])
            if min_positions[0] <= i - size:
                min_values.popleft()
                min_positions.popleft()

            if max_positions[0] <= i - size:
                max_values.popleft()
                max_positions.popleft()

        while 0 < len(min_values) and value <= min_values[-1]:
            min_values.pop()
            min_positions.pop()
        min_values.append(value)
        min_positions.append(i)

        while 0 < len(max_values) and max_values[-1] <= value:
            max_values.pop()
            max_positions.pop()
        max_values.append(value)
        max_positions.append(i)

    yield (len(array), min_values[0], max_values[0])

This clearly takes memory O(size). What's less obvious is that it takes time O(n) to process an array of length n. But we can see that with amortized analysis. To each element we'll attribute the cost of checking the possible value that is smaller than it, the cost of some later element checking that it should be removed, and the cost of being added. That accounts for all operations (though this isn't the order that they happen) and is a fixed amount of work per element.
Also note that the memory needed for this part of the solution fits within O(n).
So far I'd consider this a well-known dynamic programming problem. Now let's make it more challenging.
We will tackle the partition problem as a traditional dynamic programming problem. We'll build up an array best_weight of the best partition to that point, and prev_index of the start of the previous partition ending just before that point.
To build it up, we'll use the above algorithm to take a previous partition and add one of min_len to it. If it is better than the previous, we'll save its information in those arrays. We'll then scan forward from that partition and do that up to max_len. Then we move on to the next possible start of a partition.
When we're done we'll find the answer from that code.
Here is what that looks like:
def partition_array(numbers, min_len, max_len):
    if max_len < min_len or len(numbers) < min_len:
        return (None, None)

    best_weight = [None for _ in numbers]
    prev_index = [None for _ in numbers]

    # Need an extra entry for off of the end of the array.
    best_weight.append(None)
    prev_index.append(None)

    best_weight[0] = 0

    for i, min_value, max_value in window_mins_maxes(min_len, numbers):
        window_start_weight = best_weight[i - min_len]
        if window_start_weight is not None:
            j = i
            while j - i < max_len - min_len and j < len(numbers):
                new_weight = window_start_weight + max_value - min_value
                if best_weight[j] is None or best_weight[j] < new_weight:
                    best_weight[j] = new_weight
                    prev_index[j] = i - min_len

                if numbers[j] < min_value:
                    min_value = numbers[j]
                if max_value < numbers[j]:
                    max_value = numbers[j]
                j += 1

            # And fill in the longest value.
            new_weight = window_start_weight + max_value - min_value
            if best_weight[j] is None or best_weight[j] < new_weight:
                best_weight[j] = new_weight
                prev_index[j] = i - min_len

    if best_weight[-1] is None:
        return (None, None)
    else:
        path = [len(numbers)]
        while prev_index[path[-1]] is not None:
            path.append(prev_index[path[-1]])
        path = list(reversed(path))
        partitioned = [numbers[path[i]:path[i+1]] for i in range(len(path)-1)]
        return (best_weight[-1], partitioned)

Note that we do O(1) work for each possible start and length. And so that is time O((max_len + 1 - min_len)*n). And the data structures we used are all bounded above by O(n) in size. Giving the overall efficiency that I promised in the comments.
Now let's test it.
print(partition_array([5, 8, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1], 3, 7))
print(partition_array([1, 6, 2, 2, 5, 2, 8, 1, 5, 6], 3, 4))
print(partition_array([5, 8, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1, 2], 4, 5))

And the output is:
(12, [[5, 8, 4], [5, 1, 3], [5, 1, 3, 1]])
(16, [[1, 6, 2], [2, 5, 2, 8], [1, 5, 6]])
(None, None)


And with that,, I'm done with this conversation. You have been nothing but unpleasant from the start. And as I said, I have no reason to attempt to educate someone whose ignorance keeps being demonstrated in your attempts to explain why I am wrong.

I have an idea to get a log factor. I tried to outline it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78393448/2034787 . Does it make sense, generally?

@גלעדברקן I would need to see it implemented to make sense of it. I know I came up with a number of tricks to be able to reuse calculations from the previous m-n window for the next one and avoid a lot of work. But the thing I couldn't find a way around is that a better partition can come from moving the end of the last interval out farther, or from moving the beginning of that interval to get a better previous choice. Every way I found to be clever added complexity, but not always speed.

It took me until today to work on this :) I added a link in my answer to a comparison between my window updating method and your code, just to confirm correctness. I haven't been able to consider theoretical complexity of how many times the updates would be needed so I added a crude iteration count, which I can't seem to get above 3×N. Maybe you can think of a degenerate case? :) https://ideone.com/lVXrJM

Just an alternative for btilly's window_mins_maxes, also O(len(array)) time and O(size) space:
from itertools import accumulate

def window_mins_maxes(size, array):
    leftmins = None
    for stop in range(size, len(array) + 1):
        if not leftmins:
            left = array[stop-size : stop][::-1]
            right = array[stop-1 : stop+size]
            leftmins = list(accumulate(left, min))
            leftmaxs = list(accumulate(left, max))
            rightmins = accumulate(right, min)
            rightmaxs = accumulate(right, max)
        yield (
            stop,
            min(leftmins.pop(), next(rightmins)),
            max(leftmaxs.pop(), next(rightmaxs))
        )

The idea: If you want the minimum of some array range, split the range into a left part and a right part, and take the minimum of the left's minimum and the right's minimum.
For example for 10 elements and window size 4:
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

 L L L L
       R

   L L L
       R R

     L L
       R R R

       L
       R R R R

         L L L L
               R

           ...

The Ls mark the left part and the Rs mark the right part of the window. The right part is growing, so its minima are just its cumulative minima. The left part is shrinking, so its minima are it's reversed cumulative suffix minima.
Whenever I don't have left-part minima, I compute a chunk of them and reset the right part, as shown in the last step above.
I made L and R overlap so they're never empty, not even when size=1.
Attempt This Online!

Let f(i, j) equal max(A[i]..A[j]) - min(A[i]..A[j]).
Let's consider the dynamic program extending the minimal interval, f(i - a + 1, i), to the left as it relates to changing maximum mx or changing minimum mn.
We look left to the closer of the next higher value from mx or the next lower value from mn, of which there can be only one if it exists. There are two relevant possibilities: (1) there is a value, mx'/mn', and it is within the allowed interval, [i - b + 1, i]; and (2) there is no such value or it is beyond the allowed interval.
For (2), we generally return
f(i - a + 1, i) + max(dp[j])
  where max(0, i - b - 1) ≤ j < i - a

We can have range max queries for dp[j] in O(log n) time.
For (1), we'd like to return
the greatest

f(i - j, i) + max(dp[k])
  where m = A[j]
    and j' ≤ k < i - j
    
where m is chosen in order from the
strictly increasing sequence, indexed
to the left, mx, mx', mx''...; or from
the strictly decreasing sequence,
indexed to the left, mn, mn', mn''...

The first A[j] is the leftmost minimum
or maximum in the interval [i - a, i].

j' is the index of the next m or 0, and
not less than i - b - 1.

First, observe that we can look only at the change from one m to the next and extract f(i - a, i), as well as m as a constant:
f(i - a, i) - mx + mn +

the greatest

mx' - mn' + max(dp[k])
  where A[j'] = m'
    and j'' < k < i - j'
    
where m' is chosen in order from the
strictly increasing sequence, indexed
to the left, mx, mx', mx''...; or from
the strictly decreasing sequence,
indexed to the left, mn, mn', mn''...

The first A[j'] is the leftmost minimum
or maximum in the interval [i - a + 1, i].

j'' is the index of the next m or 0, and
not less than i - b - 1.

The following code uses an ordered queue for the updated window choices of min, max and dp index, but deletion of list elements is not efficient. Could such an ordered list be maintained in O(log n) for deletion?
I'm not sure how to prove complexity of the update method for windows with new, dominant max or min so I added a crude count of iterations for those updates, which seem to me should be the most likely to lead to higher complexity. I haven't seen them go above three times the length of the input.
Code with random comparison to btilly's answer: https://ideone.com/lVXrJM
Python code
import collections


debug = False


# O(n) method to get maximum value
# of the dp table within an index range.
# Could be done in O(log n) with a tree.
def get_max_dp(dp, l, r):
  if r == -1:
    return (0, -1)
  if r < 0:
    return (-float("inf"), -1)

  max_val = 0 if l == -1 else dp[l]
  index = l

  for i in range(l + 1, r + 1):
    if dp[i] > max_val:
      max_val, index = dp[i], i

  return (max_val, index)


# Updates the queue of max values and
# returns the index in the list for the current
# max in the range [i - a + 1, i]
def update_and_get_maxs(maxs, A, i, a, b):
  while maxs and maxs[0] <= i - b:
    maxs.popleft()
  while maxs and A[i] >= A[maxs[-1]]:
    maxs.pop()
  maxs.append(i)
  for j in range(len(maxs)):
    if maxs[j] > i - a:
      return j


# Updates the queue of min values and
# returns the index in the list for the current
# min in the range [i - a + 1, i]
def update_and_get_mins(mins, A, i, a, b):
  while mins and mins[0] <= i - b:
    mins.popleft()
  while mins and A[i] <= A[mins[-1]]:
    mins.pop()
  mins.append(i)
  for j in range(len(mins)):
    if mins[j] > i - a:
      return j


# O(n) method to get the best of all windows
# tracked. Could be maintained in O(log n) and
# queried in O(1).
def get_max_from_leftmosts(A, leftmosts):
  best = -float("inf")
  for (t, max_idx, min_idx, dp_idx) in leftmosts:
    best = max(best, t)
  return best


# Method to get the left (lower) bound index
# for the choice of dp value for a window.
def get_left(A, leftmosts, j, i, a, b):
  if A[leftmosts[j+1][1]] == A[leftmosts[j][1]]:
    return leftmosts[j][2]
  elif A[leftmosts[j+1][2]] != A[leftmosts[j][2]]:
    return max(leftmosts[j][1], leftmosts[j][2])
  else:
    return leftmosts[j][1]


# Main method
def f(A, a, b):
  dp = [-float("inf")] * len(A)
  maxs = collections.deque()
  mins = collections.deque()

  # A list of relevant windows stored as tuples:
  # [value, max index, min index, dp choice for window]
  leftmosts = collections.deque()

  # Previous (max, min) for the [i - a, i] window
  prev = (None, None)

  def print_state():
    print(f"dp: {dp}")
    print(f"maxs: {maxs}")
    print(f"mins: {mins}")
    print(f"leftmosts: {leftmosts}")
    print(f"prev: {prev}")

  iterations = 0

  for i in range(len(A)):
    if debug:
      print(f"\ni: {i}")

    mx_a_idx = update_and_get_maxs(maxs, A, i, a, b)
    mn_a_idx = update_and_get_mins(mins, A, i, a, b)
    if debug:
      print(f"mx_a_idx: {mx_a_idx}")
      print(f"mn_a_idx: {mn_a_idx}")

    curr_max_idx = maxs[mx_a_idx]
    curr_min_idx = mins[mn_a_idx]
    if debug:
      print(f"curr_max_idx: {curr_max_idx}")
      print(f"curr_min_idx: {curr_min_idx}")

    curr = (curr_max_idx, curr_min_idx)

    # New max or min
    if i + 1 == a or (i + 1 > a and prev != curr):
      leftmosts.append([
          None,
          curr_max_idx,
          curr_min_idx,
          None])

      for j in range(len(leftmosts) - 2, - 1, -1):
        [t, max_idx, min_idx, dp_idx] = leftmosts[j]

        # Similar to the queues for maxes and mins --
        # the new max or min should carry through to all
        # preceding window choices while it's dominant.
        should_update = (A[curr_max_idx] >= A[max_idx]
             or A[curr_min_idx] <= A[min_idx])

        if should_update:
          # Crude count of iterations to try to evaluate
          # time complexity of the overall method.
          iterations += 1

          if A[curr_max_idx] >= A[max_idx]:
            leftmosts[j][1] = curr_max_idx
          if A[curr_min_idx] <= A[min_idx]:
            leftmosts[j][2] = curr_min_idx

        # If two windows now have the same max and min,
        # remove the window since the dp choice can simply 
        # extend to the rightmost window.
        if (A[leftmosts[j][1]] == A[leftmosts[j+1][1]]
             and A[leftmosts[j][2]] == A[leftmosts[j+1][2]]):
          del leftmosts[j]
        # Otherwise, we can use this updated window to
        # update the dp choice for the window to its right.
        else:
          r = min(i - a, leftmosts[j+1][1] - 1,
              leftmosts[j+1][2] - 1)
          l = get_left(A, leftmosts, j, i, a, b)
          if debug:
            print(f"(j, l, r): {(j, l, r)}")
          max_dp, max_dp_idx = get_max_dp(dp, l, r)
          leftmosts[j+1][0] = (A[leftmosts[j+1][1]]
              - A[leftmosts[j+1][2]] + max_dp)
          leftmosts[j+1][3] = max_dp_idx

        if not should_update:
          break

    # Remove out-of-bounds windows
    if leftmosts and (leftmosts[0][1] <= i - b
        or leftmosts[0][2] <= i - b):
      leftmosts.popleft()

    # Regardless of if the first window, [i - a + 1, i], has
    # a new max or min, we need to update its choice of
    # dp since we are shifting the window bounds to the
    # right. 
    if len(leftmosts) > 1:
      r = min(i - a, leftmosts[-1][1] - 1,
              leftmosts[-1][2] - 1)
      l = get_left(A, leftmosts, -2, i, a, b)
      if debug:
        print(f"(j, l, r): {(-2, l, r)}")
      max_dp, max_dp_idx = get_max_dp(dp, l, r)
      leftmosts[-1][0] = (A[leftmosts[-1][1]]
          - A[leftmosts[-1][2]] + max_dp)
      leftmosts[-1][3] = max_dp_idx

    # Update the dp choice for the leftmost window since
    # the previous choice could now be out of bounds.
    if leftmosts:
      r = min(i - a, leftmosts[0][1] - 1, leftmosts[0][2] - 1)
      l = max(i - b, -1)
      if debug:
        print(f"(j, l, r): {(-1, l, r)}")
      max_dp, max_dp_idx = get_max_dp(dp, l, r)
      leftmosts[0][0] = (A[leftmosts[0][1]]
          - A[leftmosts[0][2]] + max_dp)
      leftmosts[0][3] = max_dp_idx

    # Save the result for the current dp index 
    if i + 1 >= a:
      dp[i] = get_max_from_leftmosts(A, leftmosts)

    if debug:
      print_state()

    prev = curr

  # Crude method to detect if complexity could be
  # reaching O(n^2).
  if iterations > 3 * len(A):
    print((iterations, len(A), a, b, A))

  return dp[-1]

